# jQuery autocomplete-style search box to pull list of links from page

Tags: jquery

I have a newsroom page, with a short list of articles. I'm not using a database or a CMS for this, so for the time being, I'd like to implement a quick search functionality to parse through the list of titles using a search box.

I'd like to be able to start typing into the input box, and perhaps use .find() to parse through the list of articles, then have a list or result below the search box in a div (similar to autocomplete) and have the links to the article be clickable to the articles themselves. I'm already using jQuery, so I'd rather not have to use jQueryUI as well, so any tips on how to go about accomplishing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this sort of what you're after? [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kU7Sn/47/)

```
$(function() {
    $("#searchbox").on("keyup", function() {

        var search = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $("#results").empty()

        if(search.trim().length) {
            var hits = $("#articles .articlelink").filter(function() {
                return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(search) !== -1;
            });
            $("#results").append(hits.clone());
        }        

    });
});​
```

For limiting the number of returned links, you can use `.slice()`:

```
var hits = $("#articles .articlelink").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(search) !== -1;
}).slice(0,3); //return max three items
```

Note that using `slice()` isn't a very effective technique since it still returns all the elements and it just truncates the list after it has been created. You *could* count number of elements returned in the `filter()` but the code above is a lot cleaner. And how I'd do it unless performance actually becomes an issue.

If you want to supply a default "No result" message when searching for something that doesn't exist, just check if the `hits` array has a length of 0 or not:

```
if (hits.length) {
    $("#results").append(hits.clone());
} else {
    $("#results").append("<li>No results!</li>");
}
```

Updated fiddle with the above changes: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kU7Sn/65/)

Comment: Precisely! Thank you so much for your help. Is there a way to parse through all the links on the page, without having to add a new link to the ul each time a new entry is added?

Comment: Great! I'm not sure I understood your second question - let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Sorry about that- I do have two more questions though. How would I limit the number of results that get returned, and if someone typed in something that doesn't exist, how could I put in a "No Results" message? Thanks again!